no password for login user
I want to create user login or current user who does not need password. On login prompt, they can just give login id and password enter without password and login should happen. I used sudo su root login to change it and did not work out. I thought to eliminate shadow file entry though I am not sure what will happen. Is there a way to disable password for a user id? I have ubuntu 22.04. This is for my desktop. However, I need it with or without gui. I am only user. It's actually laptop. I do not want password prompt when I need to login.

You don't specify if you're asking about a Desktop or Server account only specifying release (22.04). If it was me, I'd tell my DM (sddm in my case) to autologin, but that can be done if you're using gdm3 too (https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/login-automatic.html.en).  You also didn't specify if this machine is used by multiple users, or only a single user (that you want to login in the future)  FYI:  It's the DM or Display Manager that acts as greeter or the login screen; thus why it's told to autologin; assuming you're talking about Desktop systems.

I did something that actually worked. I root login and edited shadow  file and deleted the hash of password for user login. Logins are without password onwards. I tried first with temporary user created. If this is what you want to suggest, I can mark it solved.

As the root user, set the password using the passwd command to not have a password.  That is, just press enter.
But this is a really bad idea and leaves your computer very unprotected.

that did not work. password required even with root login passwd <user> command
